Deviation angle of electron's original path when incident on a negatively charged wall
I have a slight question: supposing I have a free electron initially traveling at a constant velocity that is incident on a negatively charged wall at an angle, what would be the angle of deviation from the original path? How can I calculate this angle? I am designing an electron chamber for my research and am confused about figuring out the trajectory of the electrons in that chamber. Just assume that the electrons are constrained within the chamber. Any leads or ideas would be much appreciated. Also, assume there is only one electron in the chamber. I want to know the angle of deflection from the original path. th

Do you mean the electron is repelled by the wall and bounces back? Or do you mean the electron strikes the wall at an angle different the initial angle? If the wall is large the electron's path will be approximately parabolic near to the wall.

what I maent is that the electron is approaching a negatively charged wall at an angle, so that if it were to strike the wall, it would meet the wall at angle relative to the normal.

A negative charged wall is the surface of a conductor, that is a forbidden area for external low energy electrons by the Pauli exclusion principle.
Outside, there is a constant electric field with a a linear potential, yielding the Schrödinger equation
$$i \hbar \ \dot \psi(t,x,y) = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \triangle_{x,y,z} \psi + e E x \psi $$
By the typical separating ansatz $\psi=e^{i (\omega t+ k_y \ y +k_z\ z)} \ \ \phi(x) $
the eigenvalue equation is
$$-\hbar \omega +\frac {\hbar^2}{2m} (k_y^2+k_z^2) \ \phi =-\frac {\hbar^2}{2m} \ \phi'' + e \ E \ x \ \phi $$
the Airy differential equation. The solution does not make sense, because the potential is not bounded. But its possible to cut off the potential by second parallel, positive capacitor plane, such that the potential is zero outside.
Its obvious by the product solution, that the momentum parallel to the refecting wall and the total energy is conserved.
The oscillatory Airy functions in the perpendicular directions show the typically quantum interference effect of stationary incident and reflected beams, with a varying wavelength in $x$ direction by the linear dependence of the $x$-component of the kinetic energy of the beam by  the linear potential.
